# Undefined-function error about function called by my function

Tags: require, error, message-mode

I have recently moved to emacs as my mail client. I am using `message-mode` to write and send email through `notmuch`. Specifically, the major mode is called `Message[Notmuch]`.

I would like to remap `C-c C-c` (`mail-send-and-exit`) and `C-c C-s` (`mail-send`) to *safe* analogues that require a confirmation in the minibuffer before the email is sent. So far I have:

```lisp
(defun safe-mail-send-and-exit ()
  (interactive)
  (if (string-equal (read-from-minibuffer "Are you sure? ") "yes")
      (mail-send-and-exit)
    (message "Not sent!")))
```

When I call this function within `message-mode`, I get an error:

```
Symbol’s function definition is void: mail-send-and-exit
```

How can I pass the context of the email and the mode to my function?

Comment: In your question, you refer to `send-mail-and-exit` but in your code you refer to `mail-send-and-exit`.  Maybe that's why it can't find mail-send-and-exit.  Unfortunately, I'm not that familiar with [notmuch](https://notmuchmail.org/).

Comment: Hey, sorry, just a typo on my part in the post. Those should be `mail-send` and `mail-send-and-exit`, I'll edit the original post.

Comment: Emacs is telling you that function doesn't exist, so let's try to find the right one.  Temporarily undo your remapping of `C-c C-c` and then figure out what function it was originally bound to by doing `C-h k` and then `C-c C-c`.  I bet it'll be something other than `mail-send-and-exit`.

Comment: Actually, you're right. How silly of me... Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what was the function it was bound to?

Comment: Functions in Emacs Lisp are globally scoped, so if the function is defined at all, it will be available everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Put `(require 'THE-LIBRARY)` inside your definition of `safe-mail-send-and-exit`, at the beginning (just after `(interactive)`, where `THE-LIBRARY` is the library that defines function `mail-send-and-exit`.

```lisp
(defun safe-mail-send-and-exit ()
  (interactive)
  (require 'THE-LIBRARY) ; Replace THE-LIBRARY with the right library name.
  (if (string-equal (read-from-minibuffer "Are you sure? ") "yes")
      (mail-send-and-exit)
    (message "Not sent!")))
```

Or else ensure that you load that library before defining (or at least before invoking) that function. E.g.:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load THE-LIBRARY
  (defun safe-mail-send-and-exit ()
   ;; ...
   ))
```

---

Not part of your question, but consider replacing this:

```lisp
(string-equal (read-from-minibuffer "Are you sure? ") "yes")
```

with just this:

```lisp
(yes-or-no-p "Are you sure? ")
```