# Warning: void-function org-link-set-parameter

Tags: org-mode, warning, error

Anyone know why I might be getting the following warning on running emacs? I'm running org-mode 9.7 with the latest doom emacs.

```
 Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/home/seba/.emacs.d/.local/etc/@/init.29.elc’:

Error caused by user's config or system: /home/seba/.doom.d/config.el, (void-function org-link-set-parameters)
```

Comment: You are using the function in your init file before its definition is loaded. You need to `(require 'ol)` before its use.

Comment: @NickD that was it, thank you very much! What method did you use to determine that function belongs to `ol`?

Comment: `C-h f org-link-set-parameters` should tell you what file it is defined in. If necessary, you can check that file's last line to see what feature it `provide`s and then you require that feature, but in general the name of the file (without the .el suffix) is used for the feature name.

Comment: "... check that file's last line" or thereabouts: there may be a trailing comment in the file, so you may have to go back a few lines to find the `provide`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined-function error about function called by my function](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74896/undefined-function-error-about-function-called-by-my-function). (And there are likely other duplicates of this same question.)

Comment: @Drew the linked problem's error message is not the same, so it might be of use to distinguish them!

Comment: There are duplicate questions about getting a void-function error because the library that defines the function hasn't been loaded yet. (The answer being to load that library before trying to use the function.) That's *exactly* what this question and its answer are about.

Comment: @Drew indeed. for archiving purpose, it would be most helpful to be able to collect this alternative error message in the duplicate questions, otherwise it makes sense to keep them separate!

Comment: The error message is the same, no? Something in some code (file `config.el` in your case) invokes a function that' s not yet defined. If you search tag `[error]` you'll likely find N other duplicates.

Comment: Closing it as a duplicate (which it is) does not get rid of the question. It just marks is as solved through the answer to another (closely related) question. If somebody ends up with a message that matches this question, they will still be able to figure out the answer through the duplicate(s).

Comment: @NickD oh, I see! that clarifies it. then it definitely makes sense to close it